# Swift initialization of constants in a protocol

Tags: swift, interface, initialization

In Java you can initialize final static Strings in an interface.

Is there a method in Swift?

For example:

```
protocol StaticStringProtocol {
    // ERROR: Immutable property requirement must be declared as 'var' with a '{ get }' specifier
    static let staticStringInProtocol = "staticStringInProtocol"
}

extension StaticStringProtocol {
    // ERROR: Static stored properties not supported in protocol extensions
    static let staticStringInProtocolExtension = "staticStringInProtocolExtension"
}
```

Comment: why not simply read this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html ? It tells everything about protocols in Swift

Comment: In general it's not a good architecture to declare constants in interfaces. I know that many Java developers do that and then they are implementing that interface with constants to their classes but that's really abusing the concept of interfaces. An interface should provide a common interface, that is, common methods. Not constants.

Comment: No good way to do this in Swift( In this respect Java is more convenient.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha can you please explain me with an example that how you can implement that? Is protocol accept final and an initial default value? In extension we can use computed property. Then how it can be constant? I try but can not achieve final static string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update** This answer is no longer accurate. See **rghome**'s answer instead

---

No swift doesn't support that. My advice is to define a struct alongside your protocol and define all constants as immutable static stored properties. For example:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
}

struct MyProtocolConstants {
    static let myConstant = 10
}
```

Note that structs are preferred to classes, for at least one reason: classes don't support static stored properties (yet)

Comment: @S.Birklin: maybe you should change the accepted answer to rghome's one

Answer (score 18):

Actually, you can do this in Swift using protocol extensions:

Create a protocol and define the variable you want with a getter:

```
protocol Order {
    var MAX_ORDER_ITEMS: Int { get }
    func getItem(item: Int) -> OrderItem
    // etc
}
```

Define a protocol extension:

```
extension Order {
    var MAX_ORDER_ITEMS: Int { return 1000 }
}
```

An advantage of this is that you don't have to prefix the protocol name as is usual with Swift and statics.

The only problems is that you can only access the variable from within a class implementing the protocol (which is probably the most common case anyway).

Comment: this throws a compiler error: `Extensions must not contain stored properties`

Comment: It worked at the time of writing the answer. Maybe a recent Swift language update has broken it. Sorry, but I am not writing stuff in Swift at the moment, so I can't check it.

Comment: Ok, got it. No worries

Comment: Works for Swift 4.2. Thank you.

Comment: Note that it must be a computed property. You cannot use `static let foo = "foo"`

Comment: It works in Swift 5 for me, before actually implementing I got the error as mentioned by @T.Rex, but after adding an implementation everything was fine.